# Spring boot 2.7.12 is creating cyclometric complexity in webmvcfilter which doesnot happen in lower version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are trying to upgrade spring boot to 2.7.12. But faced issue with cyclometric complexity between wemnvcfilter and prometheus. This was not there earlier in lower version.

It seems there is a change related to this in latest version. But not clear

Comment: First it was allowed, in newer versions it is disabled by default. Circulair dependencies are bad, so fix them.

Comment: Yes . But it seems to be some control happening at spring end.  Unable to break it.

Comment: There is too little information here to answer it. I doubt it is the spring materials but rather something you yourself have introduced. Show the stacktrace you get.